# Run Java Application at Windows Startup

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

How can I make java application  start with Windows, without needing user interaction in netbeans ??

Comment: If you want it to run at startup, you shouldn't be running it through an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

1. Create a *.jar file using Netbeans
2. Create a batch file with the following contents:

   ```
   javaw.exe -jar path/to/file/your_jar_file.jar
   ```
3. Create a basic task in the Windows Task Scheduler. Select "When I log on" as the trigger. Set the action to starting a program, and choose your batch file as the program.